# What is the algorithm to calculate the Quantity Left

Tags: algorithm

If there is n of boys each has x number of apples say

```
boys = {b1: 20, b2: 60, b3: 10, b4: 100}
```

and there are some T number of trucks needs to filled with apples each truck has one or more boys's ids to add to the truck and the number of apples to add
say

```
trucks = 
{
    t1: [50, [b1, b2]],
    t2: [20, [b1, b2, b3]],
    t3: [20, [b3, b4]],
}
```

the truck should be filled starting from the boy of lower index to the higher
so when starting to fill t1: starts with b1 60-20=40 b1 apples left is now 0, remainig 40 will be taken from b2
now b2 should have 20 apples left

I want to calculate the apples left with any boy what is the algorithm to do that?

Comment: how would you do it with pencil and paper and in your head? ... the program would do it the same way ... don't forget that you would do comparisons in your head without actually being aware that you are doing comparisons

Answer (score 0):

You have to substract the number of apples from the boys related to the truck. In c# something like:

```
foreach (var truck in trucks)
{
    foreach (var boy in truck.boys)
    {
        var apples = Math.Min(truck.apples, boy.apples)
        boy.apples -= apples;
        truck.apples -= apples;
    }
}
```